# Change image based on selected option on Piotnet Forms (Wordpress plugin)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm currently fighting with show images based on the selected option on the Piotnet Forms (WordPress plugin).

I'm not a programmer but I'm just trying to create something simple and useful for my friend.

```html
<div>
    <button id="btn0">0</button>
    <button id="btn1">1</button>
    <button id="btn2">2</button>
    <button id="btn3">3</button>
</div>
<img src="https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus4k1.png" alt="" id="image">
<script>
    let image = document.querySelector("#image");
    let btn0 = document.querySelector("#btn0");
    let btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
    let btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");
    let btn3 = document.querySelector("#btn3");
    
    btn0.addEventListener("click", () => {
        image.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus4k1.png";
    })
    
    btn1.addEventListener("click", () => {
        image.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus1k1.png";
    })
    
    btn2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        image.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus2k1.png";
    })
    
    btn3.addEventListener("click", () => {
        image.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus20k1.png";
    })
</script>
```

And other hand I made almost the same, but I want to change an image based on the radio button on the Piotnet form, and still not working. I used IDs but nothing.

Code for this option looks like this:

```html
<img src="https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus4k1.png" alt="" id="imageone">

<script>
    let imageone = document.querySelector("#imageone");
    let form-field-p12926701-0 = document.querySelector("#form-field-p12926701-0");
    let form-field-p12926701-1 = document.querySelector("#form-field-p12926701-1");
    let form-field-p12926701-2 = document.querySelector("#form-field-p12926701-2");
    let form-field-p12926701-3 = document.querySelector("#form-field-p12926701-3");
    
    form-field-p12926701-0.addEventListener("click", () => {
        imageone.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus4k1.png";
    })
    
    form-field-p12926701-1.addEventListener("click", () => {
        imageone.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus1k1.png";
    })
    
    form-field-p12926701-2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        imageone.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus2k1.png";
    })
    
    form-field-p12926701-3.addEventListener("click", () => {
        imageone.src = "https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/korpus20k1.png";
    })
    
</script>
```

Here is a link for the test page:
https://test.ffd.sk/java/

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Where is the code for the radio buttons in the second example?

Comment: Hi @Spectric yes second code is for Piotnet forms...every radio button have ID but is much deeper in structure maybe that is problem... really i dont know

Comment: I just saw one problem and is it if i use ID in this format btn0 everthing is ok but if use this btn-0 code stop working, so plugin give me ID in format with - between numbers.